# Group by and get latest record in group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

i have a table named messages like this :
[image]

I want query for where reciever_id equal 1 and group by sender_id and get latest record.

I USED QUERY :

```
SELECT `t`.* FROM(
    SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE reciever_id = 1
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
) `t`
GROUP BY `sender_id`
ORDER BY `id`
```

[image]

AND ALSO :

```
SELECT message, MAX(created_at) 
FROM messages
WHERE reciever_id = 1
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDER BY created_at
```

[image]

Date's column created_at in picture exactly are the latest and id's also ordered and are latest also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm done this after releasing question by below query, but i think this can cost more than others... there are another way to do this with low cost?!

Can somebody say formula how times multiple joins below query has cost?

```
SELECT id,sender_id,reciever_id,seen,message,created_at
FROM messages
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM messages
    WHERE reciever_id = 1
    GROUP BY sender_id
    ORDER BY id desc
) ORDER BY created_at DESC
```